# Interpreting mutual fund performance: "Earnings" vs. gains/losses?

Tags: united-states, 401k, mutual-funds, capital-gain, losses

I have a 401K at Vanguard through my company, and I was browsing the 'performance' of my fund. I found where it breaks down my transactions, gains/loss, earnings, and overall change.

I'm guessing that gains/loss corresponds to market fluctuation.

What are earnings?

Answer (score 6):

Earnings are cash payments to your account. For example, dividends from the stocks of funds that you own.

Comment: And gain/loss may be 'realized' after sales, or just that current position shows a gain/loss.